# OpenTelemetry adding sources conflicts with custom processor

Tags: c#, .net, open-telemetry

OpenTelemetry is set up in a .net REST api project with background services to trace calls to both the endpoints and service activities.

```
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Console" Version="1.3.2" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Jaeger" Version="1.3.2" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.0-rc9.11" />

services.AddOpenTelemetry()
            .ConfigureResource(resourceBuilder =>
            {
                resourceBuilder.AddService(
                    serviceName: "main service name",
                    serviceVersion: "1",
                    serviceInstanceId: Environment.MachineName);
            })
            .WithTracing(tracerProviderBuilder =>
            {
                tracerProviderBuilder
                    .SetSampler(new AlwaysOnSampler())
                    .AddSource(CustomActivitySources.MessageServiceSource.Name)
                    .AddProcessor<TracerEndPointsFilterProcessor>() 
                    .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
                    .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation();
```

Without `.AddSource`, the endpoints tracing is working fine. Adding that feature stops producing trace for any requests to any endpoint.
To my understanding, these are 2 separate concerns and shouldn't affect each other.

My main question is how to fix this, to work in both cases (adding sources and filtering them)?
Why is this happening in the first place? is something wrong with the implementation?

Any pointers are appreciated.

---

Relevant code snippets:
`TracerEndPointsFilterProcessor` is a cutom processor to filter routes out from tracing:

```
internal sealed class TracerEndPointsFilterProcessor : BaseProcessor<Activity>
{
    public override void OnEnd(Activity activity)
    {
        if (IsHealthOrMetricsEndpoint(activity.DisplayName))
        {
            activity.ActivityTraceFlags &= ~ActivityTraceFlags.Recorded;
        }
    }

    private static bool IsHealthOrMetricsEndpoint(string displayName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayName))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return
            displayName.StartsWith("/version", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ||
            displayName.StartsWith("/health", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ||
            displayName.StartsWith("/swagger", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
```

Where `CustomActivitySources` is an extension used to dynamically hook up activities

```
internal static class CustomActivitySources
{
    internal static readonly ActivitySource MessageServiceSource = new("MessageService");

    static CustomActivitySources()
    {
        ActivitySource.AddActivityListener(new ActivityListener()
        {
            ShouldListenTo = _ => true,
            Sample = (ref ActivityCreationOptions<ActivityContext> _) => ActivitySamplingResult.AllData,
        });
    }
}
```

for example, any non-http api related service would use it like this (in case that matters)

```
var initialTags = new ActivityTagsCollection
                {
                    //some tags
                };
const string activityName = "ServiceName";

activity = CustomActivitySources.MessageServiceSource.StartActivity(activityName,
                    ActivityKind.Consumer,
                    "trace id", initialTags);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `AllDataAndRecorded` instead of `AllData` for the sampling worked to trace both services and endpoints